# Is it better to air fry and refrigerate my wings or to wait to air fry them tomorrow?

Tags: storage, chicken-wings

I'm going to make some chicken wings in my air fryer (https://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/food-network-kitchen/air-fryer-chicken-wings-5565422). I have 1.5 lbs of wings which is too much for me to eat in one sitting - so my question is is it better to cook them all now and then refrigerate and reheat some tomorrow or cook half now and cook the other half tomorrow?

Comment: "better" is subjective depending on your priorities. If convenience is important, reheating leftovers makes sense.. If you want the crispiest skin, then cooking fresh makes sense. But you'll need to give criteria for "better" to make your question answerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conventional wisdom says that freshly cooked food is better than re-heated food (*)

So I would cook half today and second half tomorrow.

I would maybe marinate the second half of the wings.

(*) yes there are exceptions like leftover pizza. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest dry brining the extra half and leaving uncovered overnight so you get an even crispier skin.